# How to convert a simple array to an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, associative

What is the fastest way to convert a simple array to an associative array in PHP so that values can be checked in the `isset($array[$value])`?

I.e. fastest way to do the following conversion:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$assoc = array();

foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
        $assoc[$value] = 1;
}
```

Comment: use in_array($value, $array) instead of isset($array[$value])

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[**`array_flip()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) is exactly doing that:

> **array_flip()** returns an [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in flip order, i.e. keys from *trans* become values and values from *trans* become keys.
>
> Note that the values of *trans* need to be valid keys, i.e. they need to be either [integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) or [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). A warning will be emitted if a value has the wrong type, and the key/value pair in question ***will not be flipped***.
>
> If a value has several occurrences, the latest key will be used as its values, and all others will be lost.

---

But apart from that, there is only one type of array in PHP. Even numerical ("simple", as you call it) arrays are associative.

Comment: array_flip will do it ...thanks.. but isset(array[5]) is not set but on an associative array isset(assoc_array[5]) is set...because the value is the key ...but in simple array the array index is the key ...am I missing something

Comment: @Rome: You are mixing two things here. Every array is associative. Of course `$array[5]` is not set, because the keys go from `0` to `4`. You want an array where the keys go from `1` to `5` (or in other words, you want to set the values of the on array as keys of the other). But still, both arrays are associative. The keys of `$array` are just starting from `0` and continuous integers.

Comment: note: array_fill_keys is some how faster than array_flip with my limited testing

Answer (score 42):

Your code is the exact equivalent of:

```
$assoc = array_fill_keys(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 1); // or
$assoc = array_fill_keys(range(1, 5), 1);
```

`array_flip()`, while it may work for your purpose, it's not the same.

PHP ref: [`array_fill_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php), [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

Comment: How can I apply this for two dimensional array? Thanks!

Comment: You're right. The correct way is array_fill_keys(), This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 21):

If anyone is still wondering how to do this, there is an easier solution for this by using the [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function.

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$assoc = array_combine($array,$array);
```

Comment: this will not work if two keys are the same!

Comment: This works great!! Just make sure that every key in your "key array" is unique. Also, you can just call it on the variable name of your "values array". It will replace it with the new associative array.

Comment: Note, that if performance is important array_combine is slow, consider using in_array instead

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this logic

```
$var1 = json_encode($arr1, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$var1 = json_decode($var1);
```

where $arr1 is the array that has to be converted to associative array.
This can be achieved by json_encode and the json_decode the same

Answer (score -1):

```
function simple_to_associative($array) {
    $new_array = [];
    $i = 0;
    $last_elem = end($array);
    $nr_elems = count($array);
    foreach ($array as $index=>$value) {
        if($i % 2 == 0 && $last_elem == $value) {
            $new_array[$value] = '';
        } elseif($i % 2 == 0) {
            $new_array[$value] = $array[$index + 1];
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $new_array;
}
```

Would work on any simple array of unlimited elements.