# Converting single array into multi dimensional array (grouping ) based on key

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I have the following array:

```
$arr = array("exercise__2" => "Then a set", "sets__2" => 3, "exercise__4" => "And finally a set", "sets__4" => 3);
```

What I'm now trying to do is to convert this array into a multidimensional array every time the number changes in the key.

I know we have to use `explode("__", $key)`, but I can't work out how to convert it to a multidimensional array so it would appear something like the following:

```
Array
(
 Array
 ( 
  [exercise__2] => Then a set
  [sets__2] => 3
 )
 Array
 (
  [exercise__4] => And finally a set
  [sets__4] => 3
 )
)
```

I suspect it's not too difficult but I'm frying my brain trying to work it out.

Comment: Hi, show us what you have done so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a simple array to an associative array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153360/how-to-convert-a-simple-array-to-an-associative-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `for` loop should do it:

```
$arr = array("exercise__2" => "Then a set", "sets__2" => 3, "exercise__4" => "And finally a set", "sets__4" => 3);
foreach($arr as $k =>$v) {
    $res[explode("__", $k)[1]][$k] = $v;
}
```

You can use `array_values` if you don't want the extra key in the upper array.

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/bBN5v)

Answer (score 0):

Array_chunk seems to be enough.
Array_chunk splits an array with n number of items.
The third argument is to preserve keys.

```
$arr = array("exercise__2" => "Then a set", "sets__2" => 3, "exercise__4" => "And finally a set", "sets__4" => 3);
$result = array_chunk($arr, 2, true);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [exercise__2] => Then a set
            [sets__2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [exercise__4] => And finally a set
            [sets__4] => 3
        )

)
```

https://3v4l.org/s57ua